# Android AWS SDK Version 2.2.1 - gethttprequest depricated, not able to find replacement

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been using Android AWS SDK 1.4.6 version to connect with S3object of Amazon web service. I have updated my SDK to 2.2.1 last day and found gethttprequest() method to be deprecated. 
This method is in `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream`
 package currently. However I am not able to find a replacement for that method in documentation too.

Do anyone know, which method to use as a replacement for gethttprequest()?
or any useful links could do too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's deprecated because it has no use case and is pending removal in future releases. Would you please tell me what you need it for?

Comment: Yes, the code uses it to get the amazon server date and time and uses that combination for a sync  service whenever the app comes online.

Comment: My question is if they are deprecating a method, there should be some replacement for that right?? What is it in this case?? Or you are saying like they have decided the method is useless and about to remove it in future release??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons that lead to the deprecation:

- Exposing implementation detail, which blocks us from phasing out Apache HttpClient. Android has been advising us to migrate from Apache HttpClient to HttpURLConnection since 2011 (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). With this in mind, in [v2.2.0 release](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/7859064698132437) we introduced an abstraction of the Http transportation layer (see [`com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/HttpClient.html)), with a default implementation [`UrlHttpClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/UrlHttpClient.html) powered by [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). The Apache HttpClient implementation is still supported during the transition. Customer can implement it with their favorite Http library like Volley or OkHttp.  During this process, we had to deprecate or remove anything that is bound to a particular implementation, like `getHttpRequest()` which returns `HttpRequest`, a class from Apache HttpClient.
- No real use case of `getHttpRequest()`. It was there only to support S3ObjectInputStream.abort() operation. All other usages weren't intentional. The abort is done without using `getHttpRequest()` in the latest release.

The server date or time from the response isn't part of the Amazon S3 APIs. It should be correct, but I suggest you not rely on it. There are many ways to get the date or time, say NPT time server or from system.

Comment: Thanks Yangfan. You really explained it well. As you have said, I am now using the     formatRFC822Date method  from Dateutils in AWS SDK to get the date and time from the server. 
Thank you again.